# Is there any API to access faceID data

Tags: ios, face-id

Is there any API to access faceID data? With data I do not mean the ID of a user or something in this way but I mean the result of the projection of the 30.000 point on the user face as a map or something similar.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please read the question before commenting. Am I asking for a recommandation or a library..?? I am asking if it's possible to do something with cocoa touch and if yes how.

Comment: API falls under off-site resource. And even if it didn't, this question still falls under "too broad"

Comment: API means interface. Did apple provide an interface to allow developer use the data that can be capture by the faceID sensore. I don't think ths is too broad and I don't underdstand the downvotes.

Comment: Questions that ask "is there an API out there that does this" get closed all the time under "asking for a recommendation". That's why you have downvotes and that's why 4 people voted up the 1st comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no public API for getting any information about the point cloud. Same as with Touch ID.

The only available API is whether it's enabled or not and whether the user successfully authorized or not. That's it. See the documentation for `LAContext` for the only related API.